# content security policy frame-ancestors

Tags: security, iframe, frame, content-security-policy, mozilla

I'm trying to load my content into an IFrame, so I implemented the Content-Security-Policy header: Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors http://*.example.com/abc.html.

I am able to load the content on iframe when I give the header as
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors http://*.example.com/.

But when I change the header to:
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors self http://*.example.com/abc.html.
then the content on iframe is getting loaded for the first time but gives below error when I refresh the web page

Refused to display 'https://....' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: frame-ancestors self http://*.example.com/abc.html.

Can anyone tell why its giving error on refreshing the page.
Also does frame-ancestors considerers the full url (http://*.example.com/abc.html) or only the hostname like http://*.example.com?

Comment: CSP frame-ancestors can only restrict framing, so setting it won't make it easier to load. It is not clear on which of the pages you set the CSP. If A frames B then frame-ancestors on B will determine if A is allowed to frame the content, while frame-ancestors only on A will have no impact. You should make your question more clear. Finally it is 'self' with single quotes.

Comment: Hi @Halvor Sakshaug , thanks for answering.
I am trying to load some content from A into an iframe of B.
for that I have set a CSP header on the server of A 
and getting the errors as mentioned above.
Also can u please elaborate 'If A frames B' ? does it mean B is getting loaded on iframe of A?

Comment: Yes if A frames B means that Site A is loading Site B into an iFrame.
The frame-ancestors have to be set on Site B.

Comment: You cannot specify file names in the frame-ancestors.. only URLs or IP addresses are allowed..

Internet hosts by name or IP address, as well as an optional URL scheme and/or port number, separated by spaces. The site's address may include an optional leading wildcard (the asterisk character, '*'), and you may use a wildcard (again, '*') as the port number, indicating that all legal ports are valid for the source. Single quotes surrounding the host are not allowed.

Answer (score 8):

Chrome browser has a [bug](https://csplite.com/csp/test355/#bug_Chrome_path_frame-ancestors) - it's not support paths in the `frame-ancestors` directive. Safari nas the same bug, and only lasets Firefox supports paths in this directive.

So for `frame-ancestors` instead of `http://.example.com/abc.html` you have to use `http://.example.com` host-source.
For other directives you can use paths and filenames.

Comment: Is this bug present in Edge Chromium too?

Comment: I think - yes, but I don't have an Edge Chromium browser for real testing. You can test any browser using the link above.

Comment: It is not a bug, it is according to the specification, it must be a host-source, scheme-source, 'self' or 'none.

Comment: It's a bug since the CSP specification defines the [host-source including the paths](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#grammardef-host-source) as well as the scheme, the port number and the file name. Also note that according to spec, the `frame-ancestors` does not support a wildcard `*`, but in real life it supports it. Therefore, the specification is not always the final truth - browsers can interpret it in their own way.

Comment: Is it listed on https://bugs.chromium.org/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Without a working example it is hard to know exactly what the problem is. But based on the specification, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors, some adjustments to your CSP can be advised:

- Remove the path, it is not according to the specification to use more than the scheme, host and port.
- Use the expected scheme (http/https) or remove the scheme.
- Use wildcard https://*.example.com, not just https://.example.com
- Use 'self', not self

Comment: Regarding 
Remove the path, it is not according to the specification to use more than the scheme, host and port.
as mentioned by @granty - is this a bug then? Or are path-parts not supported for CSP Frame Ancestors?

Comment: As the specification says, it can only be a host-source, scheme-source, 'self' or 'none'. Not accepting path is according to the specification, so that is not a bug.